# AFNetworking -- What to use for GET?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Should I use the AFHTTPRequestOperation.h or the AFJSONRequestOperation.h to request a resource (ascii) over http GET?

I was not able to find any example code for this simple task, does everybody use the JSON request method and class even though they are not necessarily requesting JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AFJSONRequestOperation` will try to decode response as json to an object, since you don't need that at all you should probably use `AFHTTPRequestOperation`